# ListPicker only shows first item?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm using the Windows Phone Toolkit (latest version installed via NuGet) to create a ListPicker on my Windows Phone page. I've defined a simple ListPicker as follows:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstPicker">
   <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="First Item" />
   <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Second Item" />
   <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Third Item" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

But when I run the app all I see is the first item. Having searched around I can see this is an old bug from 2011 ([only the first listpicker opens windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701150/only-the-first-listpicker-opens-windows-phone)) but as I installed from Nuget I should have the latest version. I've also tried downloading the source from CodePlex and referencing a local build but I get the same problem.

This is a Windows Phone 7.1 application so I'm referencing the WP7 assembly.

Anyone know what might cause this in an application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ListPickerMode property.

Normal (this is the default value) -  only the selected item is visible on the original pag.
Expanded -  all items are visible on the original page.
Full -all items are visible in a separate Popup.

I tried your xaml and it worked fine for me.  I referenced the Aug13 toolkit.  Here is my full xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="ListpickerExpanding.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstPicker">
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="First Item" />
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Second Item" />
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Third Item" />
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: I see this when I run it and tap on the control]

if you are still having problems, please paste your full xaml here.

Comment: can you paste the entire xaml